# Stored procedure that returns a table with a matrix

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I've got the following 3 tables.

**Staff:**

```
Name, LastName, SSN
```

**Course Instance:**

```
Course, Year, Period
```

**Attended By:**

```
Course, SSN, Year, Period, Hours
```

I'm trying to make a stored procedure that returns a table with a matrix over the first 4 course instances in a given year (taken as parameter to the procedure).

The returned matrix needs to look something like this:

```
Name | LastName | Course | Course | Course | Course
```

The four different `Course` are the first four courses from a given year, so what I've got now is this code to find those courses:

```
DECLARE myCursor CURSOR FOR
   SELECT top 4 Course 
   FROM Course Instance 
   WHERE Year = @year 
   ORDER by Period
```

The rest of the matrix should just get the values from the tables above somehow, basically every Staff member that has Attended any of the Courses should be in the matrix with correct information. And under each `Course` column I want the number of hours from the attending staff.

Sample tables

Staff:

```
Name | LastName | SSN 
Steve  Lastname   234 
Pete   Steven     132
```

Course Instance:

```
Course | Year | Period 
DVA123   2013   1 
DVA222   2014   2
```

Attended by:

```
Course | SSN | Year | Period | Hours 
DVA123   234   2013   1        200 
DVA222   132   2014   2        50
```

Expected output from this:

```
Name | LastName | DVA123 | DVA222 | nothing | nothing
Pete   Steven     200
Steve  Lastname            50
```

Comment: use self left join.else share sample data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am unsure of exactly how CourseInstance links to attended by, but you can achive this using [PIVOT](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) and [ROW_NUMBER](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx):

```
WITH Data AS
(   SELECT  s.Name, 
            s.LastName, 
            s.SSN,
            ci.Course,
            CourseNum = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY s.SSN ORDER BY ci.Period)
    FROM    CourseInstance ci
            INNER JOIN AttendedBy a
                ON a.Course = ci.Course
                AND a.Year = ci.Year
                AND a.Period = ci.Period
            INNER JOIN Staff s
                ON s.SSN = a.SSN
    WHERE   ci.Year = @year 
)
SELECT  pvt.Name,
        pvt.LastName,
        Course1 = pvt.[1],
        Course2 = pvt.[2],
        Course3 = pvt.[3],
        Course4 = pvt.[4]
FROM    DATA
        PIVOT
        (   MAX(Course)
            FOR CourseNum IN ([1], [2], [3], [4])
        ) pvt;
```

It uses `MAX(Course)`, but this is not really relevant since `CourseNum` is unique to each `SSN` you are only ever selecting the max of one row anyway. You could just as easily use `MIN`.

---

I do not advocate this approach one bit, but nevertheless, it will get you started should you chose the dynamic SQL approach instead of doing this in the presentation layer:

```
DECLARE @Courses NVARCHAR(MAX) = STUFF((SELECT  TOP 4 ',' + QUOTENAME(course)
                                        FROM    (   SELECT  course, Period, SortOrder = 0
                                                    FROM    CourseInstance
                                                    WHERE   Year = @Year
                                                    UNION ALL

                                                    -- THIS IS REQUIRED TO FILL GAPS WHERE THERE AREN'T ENOUGH COURSES
                                                    SELECT  TOP 4 
                                                            'Nothing' + CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY object_id) AS CHAR(1)),
                                                            0,
                                                            1
                                                    FROM    sys.all_objects
                                                ) t
                                        ORDER BY SortOrder, Period, course
                                        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
                                        ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '');


DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX) = 
    '   SELECT  Name, LastName, ' + @Courses + '
        FROM    (   SELECT  s.Name, s.LastName, s.SSN, ci.Course, a.Hours
                    FROM    AttendedBy a
                            INNER JOIN Staff s
                                ON s.SSN = a.SSN
                            INNER JOIN CourseInstance ci
                                ON a.Course = ci.Course
                                AND a.Year = ci.Year
                                AND a.Period = ci.Period
                ) d
                PIVOT
                (   SUM(Hours)
                    FOR Course IN (' + @Courses + ')
                ) pvt;';

EXECUTE SP_EXECUTESQL @SQL;
```

Comment: Almost what I was looking for, how could I modify this to instead of typing out "Course1, Course2" etc typing the Actual name of the Courses and under the columns get the Hours from the attending staff table

Comment: I am not sure exactly what you mean, please can you update your question with some sample data and expected output?

Comment: Added some sample data to tables with expected output, hope it makes it clearer what I'm trying to achieve. (nothing just means it's supposed to be left blanc)

Comment: You can't do this without using Dynamic SQL, and for what it's worth I don't recommend doing it at all. This it seems like a bizarre requirement to have data as your column headers. Can you not handle this in your application layer?

Comment: Maybe, I guess I'll have to look into Dynamic SQL and see if I can find a solution to it then, thanks!

Comment: Also to clarify, the first row is not supposed to be the column headers, its just the first row in the matrix if that makes any difference

Comment: That last edit appears to be what I'm looking for, however I get some errors from it, any idea why I get these? http://i.imgur.com/L3IkEhq.png

Comment: I guess you are using SQL Server 2005? Instead of `DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX) = '...'` You will need to declare it and assign separately, i.e `DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX); SET @SQL = '...'`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48392/discussion-between-jacco-and-garethd)